# jQuery selector performance difference

Tags: jquery, performance, performance-testing

What is the difference between those 2 selectors? Can I use second one in order to optimize my scripts?

```
$('#'+idTest);  
jQuery(document.getElementById(idTest));
```

According to my test on http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-speeds/4 , second one is 3 times faster (comparing `1,026,651 [Ops/sec]` with second one `3,778,351 [Ops/sec]`).

Comment: Yes, it's faster but... **will you ever need that optimization**? Count how many times you write code like that and then count how much longer your script will be. If you don't have a page with few millions of tags...

Comment: you can still cache element in most case

Comment: The only reason i'd use `document.getElementById(idTest)` over `$('#'+idTest)` is when i'm writing a script that doesn't necessarily need jQuery to operate. jQuery already does this optimization internally, it's just hidden behind a few if statements, regexp tests, and functions which makes it take longer than the native version.

Answer (score 0):

The second is twice faster for me (jsperf too, with remove function).

You can use both, but the first is more readable.
If you need this kind of optimization, you shouldn't even use jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$('#'+idTest);
```

internally uses document.getElementById to get the element.

But jQuery have to parse the string selector `'#'+idTest` against its rules. This is there overhead comes from.